Can I Knit *.Rmd in VScode with renv
When I use Knit Rmd, the .libPaths() shows the global setting. However, when I run chunk, .libPaths() shows my existed renv. The environment for knitting is not the same as the environment where I work.
I want to knit Rmd in the environment where I work by VScode. How to adjust the VScode setting?

"r.useRenvLibPath": true  This can make the R run under renv when clicking open preview.
